# Rails 3 selecting only values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In rails 3, I would like to do the following:

```
SomeModel.where(:some_connection_id => anArrayOfIds).select("some_other_connection_id")
```

This works, but i get the following from the DB:

```
[{"some_other_connection_id":254},{"some_other_connection_id":315}]
```

Now, those id-s are the ones I need, but I am uncapable of making a query that *only* gives me the ids. I do not want to have to itterate over the resulst, only to get those numbers out. Are there any way for me to do this with something like :

```
SomeModel.where(:some_connection_id => anArrayOfIds).select("some_other_connection_id").values()
```

Or something of that nautre?

I have been trying with the ".select_values()" found at [Git-hub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7530c5224c77202d62f44a26ae5036d1dc00f579/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L276), but it only returns "some_other_connection_id".

I am not an expert in rails, so this info might be helpful also:

The "SomeModel" is a connecting table, for a many-to-many relation in one of my other models. So, accually what I am trying to do is to, from the array of IDs, get all the entries from the other side of the connection. Basicly I have the source ids, and i want to get the data from the models with all the target ids. If there is a magic way of getting these without me having to do all the sql myself (with some help from active record) it would be really nice!

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried: `SomeModel.where(:some_connection_id => anArrayOfIds).select("some_other_connection_id").map &:some_other_connection_id`

Comment: Nice. That did in fact return only the ids! :D 

What does this do? Does it itterate over the resuls, and select the value from the hashmap with key "some_other_connection_id"? Or does it lazy-load it?

Comment: No it iterates over the results, no lazy loading here. Sorry!

Comment: Aww :( Ohh well. It works now. Thanks anyway :) (btw. Consider writing it as an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SomeModel.where(:some_connection_id => anArrayOfIds).select("some_other_connection_id").map &:some_other_connection_id
```

This is essentially a shorthand for:

```
 results = SomeModel.where(:some_connection_id => anArrayOfIds).select("some_other_connection_id")
 results.map {|row| row.some_other_connection_id}
```

Look at [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) for details on `map` method.

Beware that there is no lazy loading here, as it iterates over the results, but it shouldn't be a problem, unless you want to add more constructs to you query or retrieve some associated objects(which should not be the case as you haven't got the ids for loading the associated objects).

Comment: so in this case the `&:` just `converts some_other_connection_id`  to a bock that is just the accessor method for that attribute on each row? I am new and still have trouble understanding that thing sometimes...

Answer (score 9):

Try [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method

```
SomeModel.where(:some => condition).pluck("some_field")
```

it works like

```
SomeModel.where(:some => condition).select("some_field").map(&:some_field)
```